# TextToSpeech using WakefulBroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, text-to-speech

How can I use the the Text To Speech functionality `onPause` method using `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` I made the following classes for the purpose:
I am using Receiver for the GCM Push Notification and this code works fine `onReceive` method but when app is onPause state and the notification dispaly in `NotificatioManager` at that moment app crashed, help me to sort this problem
**GcmBroadcastReceiver**

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

Context mContext;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
            mContext = context;
            ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            List<RunningTaskInfo> services = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            if (!services.get(0).topActivity.getPackageName().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(context.getPackageName().toString()))
            {
                Speaker speaker = new Speaker(mContext);
                speaker.allow(true);
                speaker.speak("asdas","asdas");
            }
}
}
```

**Speaker.class**

```
public class Speaker implements OnInitListener {

private TextToSpeech tts;
private boolean ready = false;
private boolean allowed = false;

public Speaker(Context context){
    tts = new TextToSpeech(context, this);
}
public void allow(boolean allowed){
    this.allowed = allowed;
}

@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    if(status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS){
        tts.setLanguage(new Locale("en-AU"));
        ready = true;
    }
    else{
        ready = false;
    }
}
public void speak(String welcomeMessage, String body){

    if(allowed) {
        HashMap<String, String> hash = new HashMap<String,String>();
        hash.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM,
                String.valueOf(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION));
        tts.setSpeechRate((float) 0.8);
        tts.speak(welcomeMessage, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, hash);
        tts.playSilence(500, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        tts.speak(body, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, hash);
    }
}
}
```

Following exception i have faced

```
Caused by: android.content.ReceiverCallNotAllowedException:
BroadcastReceiver components are not allowed to bind to services
at android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext.bindService(ContextImpl.java:173)
at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.connectToEngine(TextToSpeech.java:627)
at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.initTts(TextToSpeech.java:597)
at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.<init>(TextToSpeech.java:553)
at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.<init>(TextToSpeech.java:527)
at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.<init>(TextToSpeech.java:512)
at sss.sss.sss.Speaker.<init>(Speaker.java:20)
at sss.sss.sss.GcmBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(GcmBroadcastReceiver.java:47)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should start your service in `onReceive` passing the message to speak

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
     intent.setAction("speak");
     intent.putExtra("welcome_message", "asdas");
     intent.putExtra("body", "asdas");
     startService(intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                MyService.class.getName())));
      // Where MyService is the service that you implements TTS
}
```

Then in the service class

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    if (intent != null)
    {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if ("speak".equals(action))
        {
             // check if TTS is initialize if so speak the extra
             // otherwise save the extra to class members and when onInit is called
             // check if these class members are null then speak 
        }
    }
}
```